# ListShuttle valueActionListener Not getting called

Tags: jsf, richfaces

below is my listshuttle xhtml which contains converter as well, I have created the converter and it reads the value, but when I try assign the value for particular user the "ValueActionListener" of listshuttle is not getting called. 
Please help me out to solve this,

below is the xhtml and java code for your reference

```
<h:form id="listShuttleForm">

        <hr align="left" id="h1" style="!important; width: 250px; "/><br />
        <rich:listShuttle sourceValue="#{roleAction.availableUserGroupsList}" id="assignUserGroupListShuttleId"
            targetValue="#{roleAction.assignedUserGroupInfoList}" var="userGroupInfo" listsHeight="300"
            sourceListWidth="190" targetListWidth="200" sourceCaptionLabel=" #{localeValue.availableUserGroups}"
            targetCaptionLabel="#{localeValue.assignedUserGroups}" converter="userGroupConverter"
            valueChangeListener="#{roleAction.assignedUserGroupsListener}" ajaxRendered="true">

            <rich:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{userGroupInfo.groupName}"></h:outputText>
            </rich:column>
            <a4j:support event="onlistchanged"    reRender="msgId" />
            <a4j:support event="onorderchanged" reRender="msgId" />
        </rich:listShuttle>

        </h:form>
```

java code:-

```
public String assignedUserGroupsListener(ValueChangeEvent event){
    System.out.println("inside assignedUserGroupListenerasdf");
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Map<String, Object> sessionMap = fc.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    HtmlListShuttle listShuttle = (HtmlListShuttle)event.getComponent();
    sessionMap.put("assignedUserGroupInfoList", listShuttle.getTargetValue());
    return null;
}
```

All suggestions would be very appreciable.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ValueChangeListener or method signature must match

```
 public void valueChangeListener(javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent).
```

And your value change listener will not be fired as soon the value is changed it will be fired when you submit the form. So it is better to have

```
    <a4j:support event="onlistchanged"   
        actionLisener="#{roleAction.assignedUserGroupsListener}" reRender="msgId" />
```

for the above action listener also the return type should be void.

Hope this helps.

Comment: did you change the method return type as void?

Comment: Yes Srikanth...but I didn't override the equals method of Object class...so it was not working, now it is working. Thanks for your help Srikanth

Comment: Glad that your problem is solved. I hope you are going through actionListener on a4j:support instead of valueChangeeListener as I mentioned ion the answer. :)

Comment: Now I get it your ValueChangeListner is working because of your a4j:support ob event onlistchanged. If you remove those a4j:support tags then your ValueChangeListner wont be called until you submit the form. Anyways your problem is solved. but remind this fact for future.